# SQL select from one table counting rows from another, inner join & count

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

I have two tables:

`player:`

```
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
| id | name   | country  | military_rank |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | John   | Portugal |            26 |
|  2 | Ninja  | Japan    |            23 |
|  3 | Elone  | Spain    |            28 |
|  4 | Markus | China    |             5 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
```

`unit`:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+
| id | player_id | unit        | number |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |         1 | bazooka     |      6 |
|  2 |         2 | bazooka     |      2 |
|  3 |         3 | bazooka     |     16 |
|  4 |         4 | bazooka     |      2 |
|  5 |         1 | machine gun |     10 |
|  6 |         4 | missile     |      2 |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

I need a SQL query which extract the names of the players (`player` table) who have military_rank higher than 25 and 5 or more bazooca units.

Here's what i tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(unit.unit) as num_baz, player.name as name 
FROM player 
INNER JOIN unit 
    ON player.id = unit.player_id 
GROUP BY unit.unit;
```

ERROR:

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Chill_Time.player.name'
>   which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
>   this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: `GROUP BY unit.unit;` change to `GROUP BY player.name;` this will solve your error... About your data, another story...

Comment: What your error says is that when you do a GROUP BY, the column in the SELECT should be in the GROUP BY so DO THAT as @JorgeCampos suggests.,

Comment: @JorgeCampos, what is it about my data?

Comment: The title of your question would be solved by fixing your group by, and for the data you want on this other question "I need a SQL query which extract the names .... " is a totally different query from the one you have.

Comment: Opps, sorry about that @JorgeCampos. You can edit if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for something like this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM player
WHERE military_rank > 25
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM unit
    WHERE player_id = player.id
    AND unit.unit = 'bazooka'
    AND number > 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess:

`SELECT player.name from player INNER JOIN unit on player.id=unit.player_id where player.military_rank < 25 AND unit.number <= 5 AND unit.unit = 'bazooka' ;`

Answer (score 0):

try below one:

```
    SELECT COUNT(dbo.unit.unit) AS num_baz, dbo.player.name
    FROM dbo.player INNER JOIN dbo.unit ON dbo.player.id = dbo.unit.player_id
    GROUP BY dbo.player.name, dbo.player.military_rank, dbo.unit.number, dbo.unit.unit
    HAVING (dbo.player.military_rank > 25) AND (dbo.unit.number >= 5) AND (dbo.unit.unit = N' bazooka')
```